# Retrieve data from codeigniter REST API (web service) with pagination

Tags: codeigniter, rest, api, curl

How to retrieve data from web service with pagination ? For now i'm able to show data. But i can't do pagination.
I'm using codeigniter 3.0.6 with curl library. This is what i use to make REST API :

```
function index_get($limit = 100, $offset = 0) {
    $MhswID = $this->get('MhswID');
    if ($MhswID == '') {
        $mhsw = $this->db->get('mhsw', $limit, $offset)->result();
    } else {
        $this->db->where('MhswID', $MhswID);
        $mhsw = $this->db->get('mhsw', $limit, $offset)->result();
    }
    $this->response($mhsw, 200);
}
```

And this is for retrieve data :

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->API="http://admin:1234@localhost/ci3_rest/index.php";
}

// menampilkan data mahasiswa
function index($limit = "", $offset = ""){
    $data['mahasiswa'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/mahasiswa'));
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
}
```

Comment: Please give more details and show your code.

Comment: edited @parth. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the function name to index_post

```
function index_post() {
    $limit = $this->post('limit'); 
    $offset = $this->post('offset');
    $MhswID = $this->post('MhswID');
    if ($MhswID == '') {
        $mhsw = $this->db->get('mhsw', $limit, $offset)->result();
    } else {
        $this->db->where('MhswID', $MhswID);
        $mhsw = $this->db->get('mhsw', $limit, $offset)->result();
    }
    $this->response($mhsw, 200);
}
```

and change the api url to

```
function index($limit = 100, $offset = 0){
    $data['mahasiswa'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/mahasiswa/index/', array('limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset));
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
}
```

and you can view the response of api by

```
var_dump($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/mahasiswa/index'));
```

and i think you must pass username and password for REST api in curl. I don't know which library you are using, its must be given in document of REST api library.

Comment: index_post used for insert data. I'm using this library for rest server https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: anyway, where is the pagination ?

Comment: Can you be more specific, where you are having problem. I have update the code, check the curl url.

Comment: no, codeigniter rest doesn't work like that. I want to use pagination when i show data. For now i can show 100 data, but i can't use pagination. i'm using this library https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver